# _references.js path not in legal form

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013, intellisense, web-essentials

Didn't find this on the web, so adding question and answer here.

Problem: Visual Studio 2013 with Web Essentials fails to update Javascript intellisense. Manually trying to refresh it by right clicking on _references.js file and selecting "Update Javascript References" throws a "Path not in legal form" error with no additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Problem in my case turned out that I was running Visual Studio as admin (website under IIS), 
and one of the file referenced by the Javascript Intellisense was blocked for the user.

Fix: Open Visual Studio -> Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Javascript -> IntelliSense -> References

In this window, select "Implicit (Web)" for the Reference Group Dropdown. In here, if a file is in a location that visual studio is unable to see, copy it to the common location and add it back.

Remove _references.js form project. 
Right click on Scripts folder -> add new -> _references.js (its one of the options). 
Restart Visual Studio. If _references isn't filled in, right click and update.

Good luck.